# Creating "Next" button, how to set target for another view?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to build an app where a user can select a location on a map and click "Next" at the top right. Doing so will take them to a description of that location.

My code for the button is in MapViewController. I've copied below my snippet for implementing a "Next" button.

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: "next")

func next()
{
    print("next")

}
```

Of course, at present the button just prints 'next' to the console, but I want it to send the user to another screen, which I've already created and coded as DescriptionViewController. How do I implement that? Do I need to set target to the other view... if so, how? Or do I need to change my next() function?

I'm still just starting off on Swift and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Another UIViewController? Did you use Storyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let descriptionButton  : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: UIImage.init(named: “Description")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(barButtonDescriptionAction(_:)))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = descriptionButton
```

---

```
@IBAction func barButtonDescriptionAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let descriptionViewControllerObject = DescriptionViewController(nibName: "DescriptionViewController", bundle:nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(descriptionViewControllerObject, animated: true)
}
```